# Fade In Content and Fade Out Current Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I am trying to Fade In a div while fading out current div I have some code here which might show what I was trying to get at!

Code :

```
 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/trftw00c/
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create an event handler for each menu, you can generalize the functionality. Keep track of the default page, and the current page.

In my jsFiddle i'm following your convention where the menu item id is equal to the item content class.

e.g. `#soap` corresponds to the content `.soap`

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/trftw00c/2/

```
var current = "home";

$('.nav-tabs').on('click','li',function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+current).toggleClass('active');
    $('#'+clicked).toggleClass('active');
    $('.'+current).fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.'+clicked).fadeIn('fast');
    })
    current = clicked;
})
```